# cvEigenVV corresponds to which API in opencv-python

Tags: opencv, python

In the c++ environment, I can use the cvEigenVV command, but I import the opencv module in python, corresponding to which API ?
the error in python: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cvEigenVV'

Comment: the first google result shows [`cv.EigenVV`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) and/or `cv2.eigen`

Comment: Thank you very much. cv2.eigen is right