# Does anyone know the new names for the following deprecated functions in opencv?

Tags: opencv

What are the newest names of functions in the latest openCV for the following functions from previous version.

1. cvGetReal2D
2. cvSetReal2D
3. cvEigenVV

Thanks,

Comment: The first two read/write values from array, so `cv::Mat::at`. The the third one it's [`cv::eigen`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga9fa0d58657f60eaa6c71f6fbb40456e3) (already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952160/cveigenvv-corresponds-to-which-api-in-opencv-python))

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you!